# Distinguish a real mouse click from fire method

Tags: java, javafx, hyperlink

I'm using javaFX to create an application.
I have a hyper-link somewhere and I've set an (onAction) for it as shown below

```
Hyperlink studentList = ...;  // It's given proper object
studentList.setOnAction(...);
```

now somewhere else i used this method to simluate a click on this hyperlink

```
studentList.fire();
```

now my problem is that how can i distinguish real click/keyPress from fire() method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Just add an `EventHandler` to the `setOnMousePressed` property. Be sure to add it to `setOnMousePressed` and not e.g. `setOnMouseClicked`, since `setOnMousePressed` is invoked before the `fire()` is invoked while `setOnMouseClicked` is invoked after.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MCVE extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox content = new VBox(5);
        content.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink("Hyperlink");

        Button fireButton = new Button("Fire hyperlink");
        fireButton.setOnAction(e -> link.fire());

        BooleanProperty mouseClicked = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

        link.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            System.out.println("Mouse click");
            mouseClicked.set(true);
        });

        link.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (!mouseClicked.get()) {
                System.out.println("No mouse click");
            }
            mouseClicked.set(false);
        });

        content.getChildren().addAll(link, fireButton);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(content));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```